# CSS3 picture full screen

Tags: html, css

How I can make full screen a picture on my website ?? I already try lots of methods, but still can't make it right.

I did this :

```
    width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
background:url(images/top.png);
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

and well, everything was alright but to make it full width I have to insert lots of text or 
 to change the height of the picture...

than I try this :

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
background:url(images/top.png);
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
```

This method works perfect, but when I add second DIV under the first one, my second DIV was on my first one...

So the question is, how I can make full screen picture on my website ! I want to have 100% height and 100% width, and when I will add second DIV everything will go under the first one.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
position: absolute;
background-image: url(images/top.png);
background-attachment: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
z-index: value;
}
```

The [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property specifies the stack order of an element.

Comment: doesn't work :( when I used your method the picture is on half of the website, and it cover just a part where the text is.

Comment: It works perfect when I used min-height: 100%; min-height: 100%; but then I can't add another page... because second DIV is on top of first div

Comment: I did, I setup z-index:-1; to set background behind the text

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're inserting the image as a background image. This automatically means that other elements fit in over the top of it. Try using an `img` tag instead:

```
<img src='myimg.png' height='100%' width='100%' />
```

You can also add some CSS to make sure it's the right size:

```
body img {
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:100%;
    min-width:100%;
}
```

Any other elements you add will now be inserted underneath the image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But now I can't insert any text on the image :) On the first image I've got few line of text. I am pretty sure that there is a way to stick image as a background + have another one under. I came up with idea to use top: 100%;, and it works because I can setup 2 images. BUT there is no response, on the tablets the background is not full screen. How people makes websites like this http://pr-emarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/modern_website_design_075Regular-Theme.jpg

Comment: That's all one image. The text on top of that image is a part of the same image; it's made with a graphic design package. If you want that kind of effect you might want to look around online for some design software.

Comment: You could also do it with JavaScript and a bit of CSS, but it might not work across devices and/or browsers.